# Newtonsoft serialize and deserialize linq2sql entities throws exception

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, json.net

From an ASPNET Core WebApi app I am returning a

```
List<Profile>
```

where Profile is a linq2sql object that contains a

```
EntitySet<Location> Locations
```

ASPNET Core uses the Newtonsoft Json serializer by default and this is the method's signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public List<Profile> FindProfile([FromBody] QueryData queryObject)
{
   ...
   return list;
}
```

On the client side I am using the Newtonsoft to deserialize the Json like this:

```
TResult result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(resultString,
                new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All });
```

but I receive the following exception:

"The specified argument is outside the valid value range."

The Json looks fine to me:

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "birthday": "1980-10-10T00:00:00",
    "canBeRecommended": false,
    "civilStatus": 0,
    "countryOfOriginId": 0,
    "sex": 2,    
    "userId": 123,
    "locations": [
      {
        "$id": "2",
        "address": "Street 1",
        "city": "New York",
        "countryId": 1,
        "profile": {
          "$ref": "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**and can actually be deserialized IF I remove the**

```
    "profile": {
      "$ref": "1"
    }
```

I have tried playing with the settings

```
PreserveReferencesHandling.None
```

and

```
PreserveReferencesHandling.All
```

of course in-sync on the server and client side, but without success.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE Exception info**

ExceptionType: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
No inner exception.
ToString() - sorry, in German:

```
"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Das angegebene Argument liegt außerhalb des gültigen Wertebereichs.
Parametername: value
   bei System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadMetadataProperties(JsonReader reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue, Object& newValue, String& id)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadMetadataProperties(JsonReader reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue, Object& newValue, String& id)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   bei <anonymized>
```

**Minimal example**
https://github.com/copiltembel/JSonDeserializeExample/tree/master/JSonDeserializeExample

Comment: 1) Can you share a [mcve] by including types that reproduce the problem?  2) Can you share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception?

Comment: Done the exception dumping. Making the example will take me a bit longer.

Comment: I've added an example as requested. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your sample is not a .NET Core app, is it?

Comment: No, but it's all the same. The important thing is the serialization/deserialization of some linq2sql entities.

Comment: I have removed the net core tag now.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and switched to using DataContractSerializer which seems to be able to deal with this kind of objects.